# How to pass a model to a Razor view from Nancy

Tags: razor, nancy

I have Razor woking with Nancy, but can't figure out how to make the view see the model.

I am rending the model with this code (where `t` is the model instance).

```
  return View[ "views/addshortcut.cshtml", t ];
```

How can I make the Razor see `t`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The model is there, just start using it. If you are talking about intellisense then you can use the @inherit statement in razor.. something like

```
@inherits Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.NancyRazorViewBase<YourNameSpace.YourModel>
```

Comment: I had to use this:
@inherits Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.NancyRazorViewBase<go.asna.com.tester> 
(typo?) but otherwise exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much!

Comment: This will work so long as you only have one of them. Often, you will be wanting to pass a collection, and have intellisense for the individual members. To do this, you need to explicitly tell Razor about your dll and your namespace in your web/app.config, as explained [here](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/issues/778). I hope I'm improving Andreas' answer (by referring to another Andreas answer :-)